# What to use to lock two flanges together?

Tags: tools

I need to hold/lock two flanges together in such a way that I can lock the mechanism preventing someone else from separating the flanges (with some form of a key).

I realize this isn't specifically a car maintenance question, but I figure this audience would be the best suited to pointing me in the right direction.

Unfortunately there are no holes in the flanges and I can not add any.

I suspect a tool or clamp must exist that would meet these needs but I can't seem to find anything, or more likely don't know what key words to use when searching.

Can anyone suggest tools or how to find such a device?

Comment: Probably need more details or a picture of exactly what you need, but probably you will have to have something fabricated or custom welded .

Comment: Assuming the device is for anti-tamper only and not meant to be any part of the flange connecting assembly, look for "lock-out tag-out" devices for blind flanges. They are like a clam shell and use a keyed lock or padlock.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Thanks for the suggestion.  I looked into that and although it is a great idea for anti-tamper, I'm looking more for something that will actually prevent someone from separating the two flanges, rather than just knowing that they were separated.  If I could find something a c-clamp vice grip that I could lock in the closed position, that would be the right concept.  Unfortunately, I can't lock the vise grips closed.  Even something like a c-clamp, if I could drill a hole through the threads and put a padlock in there, it would work, but I'm not sure if it would still be solid.

Comment: Do you need to be able to separate the flanges later? If not, what about riveting or welding?

Comment: How large are the flanges? how tamper-proof does it have to be, like just inconvenient deterrent or robustly secure?

Comment: I agree with John D, a picture would go a long way here.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips guys.  Eventually @RO' response below pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application allows, you could use something like a [V band clamp](http://www.stangtv.com/tech-stories/engine/v-band-clamps-from-race-parts-solutions/) with an anti tamper nut.  Although it wouldn't 'lock', using a fastener with an obscure head would essentially require a 'key'.

There are also [V band clamps that use a male fastener](http://www.verociousmotorsports.com/Shop-by-Brand/Precision-PW46-46mm-Wastegate-Parts/Precision-Turbo-PW46-46mm-Wastegate-V-Band-Clamp-Inlet), which would give you even more options for fasteners that require obscure tools to remove.

Comment: Thanks!  Turns out that led me to exactly what I needed to get the job done.